# how to use bundle to install bash-support for vim

Tags: bash, vim

I used to installed a vim plugin named bash-support,in order to install another You Complete Me,I installed bundle to manage vim plugins.You complete Me do installed successfully, but bash-support does not work any more.

I notice that the directory named bash-support was gone. So I guess this must be removed when install bundle. Since I realize bundle is used to manage vim plugins and bash-support is a vim plugin, so I wonder If bash-support could installed through bundle? if it is,How to do that?

I have googled is question,and find a 
[related post](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/337),it recommend me to use `Bundle 'bash-support.vim'`,but it does recognized as valid vim command.

I will be grateful if some one provide me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of information here. Let's go by parts.

### About the `Bundle` command

That's not a default Vim command. The original poster was probably referring to the [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) plugin manager.

Once you have that plugin installed, the command `Bundle 'bash-support.vim'` will install the [bash-support](https://github.com/vim-scripts/bash-support.vim) plugin.

But that plugin manager is quite dated. I would recommend you to use [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) instead.

### Using the [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager

In order to install this plugin, you can follow the [instructions](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#installation).

Once you have done that, you can actually put the following in your `.vimrc`, in order to install the [bash-support](https://github.com/vim-scripts/bash-support.vim) plugin.

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'vim-scripts/bash-support.vim'

**Put other vim plugs here**

call plug#end()
```

After that, you can install your plugins with the `:PlugInstall` command.

Notice the command refers to a `username/repository_name` in GitHub. You can use that pattern to install any plugin hosted in GitHub.

You could also just put in your `.vimrc`

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'bash-support.vim'
call plug#end()
```

That would refer to the same plugin, but it would take the [vim-scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=365) version.

In fact, [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) is extremely powerful. You can even use it to install [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/) without having to follow specific install instructions.

Just put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'bash-support.vim'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py' }
call plug#end()
```

And it will setup everything for you after `:PlugInstall`.

Answer (score 0):

myself configuration file of vim ,  [.vimrc](https://github.com/JiangYahui/vim)

1. mv .vimrc ~/
2. git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
3. Launch vim and run :PluginInstall